# Output of "netstat" shows domain I never visited

Tags: macos, netstat

I think my MacBook Pro might be hacked. The reason I found out about the `stackoverflow.com` website is because I did a `netstat` search in Terminal. My browser was closed but nevertheless it showed this:

```
tcp4       0      0  macintosh.lan.50419    stackoverflow.co.http  LAST_ACK
```

among other things. I have never visited this website in my life.

Also `netstat` results show things that I think might be not right. Also I have been trying to figure this out for the past hours and recently (maybe 20 minutes ago) my screen went black for like a second or two and this never happens.

Anybody know whats wrong?

Comment: Have you tried Anti-Virus software (yes, there's software like that for Mac, too)?

Comment: thank you for your answer but the strange thing i have never visited this website in my life I am certain of that and it didnt show up on an earlier netstat search

Comment: @Worried - your question was posted on Stack Overflow, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908149/macbook-pro-might-be-hacked?noredirect=1), and was migrated here because it was off-topic on SO. You might not have visited this site before, but you've visited a site in the network before.

Comment: stackoverflow.co appears to be a parked domain...

Comment: it doesn´t matter if it is truncated it now shows the same results in netstat with the .co

Comment: Okay. Just checked on a Mac, and you're right. I retract my earlier statements. I do think that's very silly behaviour, though. @Arjan

Comment: @Worried - if you associate your Stack Overflow and Super User accounts you should regain ownership of the question. If it hasn't happened after 24 hours e-mail the team (team@superuser.com).

Comment: @Worried please login with the same site that you logged into Stack Overflow. That way you can claim this question and leave a comment

Comment: @oKtosiTe, the truncated "fixed column width" is far more obvious when not seeing just a single line of the output.

Answer (score 6):

LAST_ACK simply means that a connection to the specified server was recently closed. It's perfectly normal that it might remain for a few minutes after closing your browser.

Comment: Doesn't "The reason i found this website is because..." sounds like he had never heard about this website before?

Comment: @oKtosiTe: Except that the output of netstat could be truncated. "stackoverflow.co" isn't a valid domain name.

Comment: @Cody: [It is, actually](http://stackoverflow.co/). [.co](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.co) is the top level domain for Colombia.

Comment: @oKtosiTe: Oh, maybe it is. It looks like they're selling .co domains globally now. Who knew. Either way, it's unlikely the netstat output indicates anything other than stackoverflow.com. It looks like stackoverflow.co is just a squatter hoping Stack Overflow Internet Services will buy it from him.

Comment: Indeed it does. @CodyGray

Answer (score 6):

How about link pre-fetching as an explanation?

Comment: Good thinking! (Though I'm not sure if that only applies to getting DNS records, or also really fetches *content*. The first won't show in the output of `netstat`, I think. The latter would indeed.)

Answer (score 4):

The output of `netstat` shows you reversed DNS addresses: a name based on an IP address. However, multiple names might exist for the same IP address.

Like both `superuser.com`,  `gaming.stackexchange.com` and `stackoverflow.com` refer to the same IP address<sup>†</sup>: `64.34.119.12`. But:

```
dig -x 64.34.119.12
```

...shows that this primarily maps to `stackoverflow.com`, even though

```
dig superuser.com
```

...shows the very same IP address.

So you probably visited one of [the Stack Exchange sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites)?

Running `netstat -n` will show you IP addresses rather than (assumed) host names.

<sup><sup>†</sup> It might even be [on the same server](http://blog.serverfault.com/post/1432571770/) but that is not relevant here.</sup>